# Is it important to track the bin, debug and release files in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

What exactly do the debug and release files in the bin folder do? I made the mistake of tracking them when I initialized my git repository. I want to remove them now. Is it alright to remove them both or are certain changes necessary to be kept?

Comment: Perhaps the first thing should have been to commit a '.gitignore' file. Using 'http://gitignore.io'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to remove them. They are generated each time the program is run in Visual Studio, so all you need to do is remove them from git tracking. They contain files for both release, and disputable debug respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The files are the compiled binary-output of your project. You do not have to track this folder.